# Not able to built WebDriverAgent in iOS mobile devices in Xcode version 14.3

Tags: xcode, appium, appium-ios, xcode14.3

Not able to built WebDriverAgent in iOS mobile devices in Xcode version 14.3. Getting error as "**Cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCTAutomationSupport.framework/XCTAutomationSupport for architecture arm64"**

*Xcode Version : 14.3
MacOS Version : 13.2.1
Appium Version : 1.22.1*

After getting that above error, i gone through the Appium site and they asked us to install Appium 2 which is 2.0.0-beta.65. After installed the latest version, i am able to build the WebDriveragent in mobile

Here, Another issue occured, when i start appium it starts in 1.22.1 version

`[Appium] Welcome to` **`Appium v1.22.3`**
`[Appium] Non-default server args:`
`[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true`
`[Appium]   allowInsecure: {`
`[Appium]   }`
`[Appium]   denyInsecure: {`
`[Appium]   }`
`[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723`

Any other workaround will helpful. I am stuck with these for past two weeks.`

Answer (score 0):

You will face this issue on MAC because WDA present inside Appium is not compatible with your XCode 14.2. When you install Appium, it is equipped with latest WDA at the time of released version for example appium 1.22.3 will come with WebdriverAgent 3.17.0

You can try installing latest WDA using this command

```
npm install -g appium-webdriveragent
```

Start webdriver agent using XCodeBuild. Hit this command to do the same

```
xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj \
           -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner \
           -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=<device_name>' \
           test
```

Here device_name is your device name for example iPhone XR
Start appium using command `appium`

Answer (score 0):

If above steps does not work for you then you have to replace your WDA manually using below steps. Here are the steps to be followed to replace older WDA to latest WDA

1. For XCode 14.2 Download latest WDA from here https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases?page=1
2. Download Source code.(zip) from above link on you mac machine
3. unzip file
4. Copy all the files and folders present inside unzipped folder
5. You have to update all these contents into WebdriverAgent present inside Appium Server folder
6. In Mac, Go to Applications
7. Right click on Appium Server GUI > Contents > Resources > App >
   node_modules > appium > node_modules > Appium-webdriver agent
8. Paste all the contents you have downloaded inside WebDriverAgent folder
9. Check for WebDriverAgent.XCodeProj
10. Open WebDriverAgent.XCodeProj in XCode
11. If project is not open click on folder icon present on top right
    corner.
12. Click on WebDriverAgent
13. In centre panel > TARGETS Select WebDriverAgentRunner
14. Click on Signing and Capabilities
15. Click on "Team" Drop down to sign in your app
16. You can select existing certificate or new certificate where you have to apple certificate
17. Find WebDriverAgent project on top.
18. select WebDriverAgentRunner from drop down
19. Select targeted device from drop down on which you want to execute test cases
20. Click on "Product" menu
21. Click on "Test"
22. It will install WebDriverAgent on you targeted device
23. Now you can try to launch new session from appium inspector

Comment: can we perform this operation dynamically ??